# Why do NDB properties need to be included in projection query when used in a filter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm wondering why you need to include certain properties in the projection query. I'm trying to get a distinct list of 'foo' properties.

```
Object.query(projection=[Object.foo], distinct=True) \
    .filter(Object.username == user.nickname()) \
    .filter(Object.bar >= value) \
    .fetch()
```

This one gives an NeedIndexError, even though the suggested index is up and running. The reason is the second filter based on bar >= value. By removing that filter, the query works perfect, yet doesn't achieve the goal.

```
Object.query(projection=[Object.foo, Object.bar], distinct=True) \
    .filter(Object.username == user.nickname()) \
    .filter(Object.bar >= value) \
    .fetch()
```

This one works, yet now you don't have a result with only distinct foos, but the carthesian product of foo and bar. Which is not what we were aiming for in the first place.

```
Object.query() \
    .filter(Object.username == user.nickname()) \
    .filter(Object.bar >= value) \
    .fetch(projection=[Object.foo])
```

This one also works, but there is no way to group by 'foo', thus resulting in a list with duplicate 'foo'-values.

There are solutions to this problem as you can see above, but both result in a larger response list. I'd like to avoid this if possible. I thus have two questions:

1. Why do the properties in the filter() sometimes need to be included in the projection? This doesn't make sense to me. Also, why does this result in an NeedIndexError and not something more appropriate?
2. Are there any solutions that don't have the drawbacks seen above? Or maybe I'm tackling this problem from the wrong side? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the index recommendation system and should be fixed in the 1.8.6 release of App Engine. The issue is that in order to provide distinct properties, these properties must be first in the sort order. Note that an inequality must also be first in the sort order. So if you have an inequality and a distinct projection, they must be on the same property.

The only reason the projection must be in the filter is because you are requesting distinct properties. You can really think of this as a projection with a group by on the same property. In order to do this grouping, the properties must be sorted to provide efficient deduplication.

The only way to execute your desired query is to perform some operation in memory (as you've mentioned in the question). Another option is to not have an inequality filter, then do this filtering in memory.

If you upgrade to the 1.8.6 SDK, you should start getting better(-ish) error messages.